# Swift: Converting string to date with timezone

Tags: ios, swift, date

I want to convert a string with the format `2023-10-10 15:30:40.345T+5:30` to date, which is something like `10 Oct 2023`.

I tried with the following `dateFormat`, it failed to parse and printed `"failed to parse timestamp"`

```
let timestampString = "2023-10-10 15:30:40.345T+5:30"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'T'ZZZZZ"
if let timestamp = dateFormatter.date(from: timestampString) {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy"
    let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: timestamp)
    print(formattedDate)
} else {
    print("failed to parse timestamp")
}
```

Comment: What's your current output? Does `timestamp` get a correct value? Which value is it, could you print it?

Comment: Updated the question with the output. @Larme

Comment: Ok, so a good way to see what's the issue since it's the dateFormat is to do `print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date())`, there you'll see what means your format and see the difference with your input string, and combined with http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns you'll see that it's missing a leading zero as said by Vadian's answer.

Comment: You can test format at https://nsdateformatter.com/. P.S. Very odd format that T is after time. By ISO standard it should be between date and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unicode standard specification for dates doesn't support time zones with a single hour digit.
It must be `+05:30`

A possible solution is to add – if necessary – the leading zero with Regular Expression

```
let timestampString = "2023-10-10 15:30:40.345T+5:30"
let consolidatedTimestampString = timestampString.replacing(/([+-])(\d:)/) {
    return $0.output.1 + "0" + $0.output.2
}
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'T'xxx"
if let timestamp = dateFormatter.date(from: consolidatedTimestampString) {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy"
    let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: timestamp)
    print(formattedDate)
} else {
    print("failed to parse timestamp")
}
```

Comment: Most likely you actually want to use `xxx` and not `ZZZZZ` for the timezone. `ZZZZZ` allows for "Z" instead of "+00:00" for GMT. `ZZZZZ` also supports timezones with seconds (are there any?). `xxx` avoids both of those potential issues.